# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP

Tags: c#, smtp

I know that this an old question but I can find a solution for my problem, here is the thing , I am trying to send a email via smtp of outlook , but I get this error message: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP, sorry for my english.

```
public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        msgToSend = message;

        string password = string.Empty;

        password = CryptoHelper.DecryptData("encoded_password", "key");

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        smtpClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            smtpClient.Dispose();
            message.Dispose();
        };

        smtpClient.SendAsync(message, null);
    }
```

Comment: That probably means your password is wrong.

Comment: Check this post to see if the solutions work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751844/smtp-5-7-57-error-when-trying-to-send-email-via-office-365

Comment: no, Is not wrong I checked it, is getting the correct password

Comment: Why you are using "password" instead of password in NetworkCredential?

Comment: I change the password and try some things of that post and nothing

Comment: Take the quotes off `"password"` in the `NetworkCredential` constructor and you should be good to go.

Comment: "password" means the password , is an example, I'm not going to put the real password

Comment: yes , but forgot about the quotes , ok my mistake put password without quotes and still not working

Comment: What component are you using? `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` does not have a constructor with two strings. Is this a third party class?

Comment: You right  Juan my mistake when I put the post is an int and Is correct in my code, and not is not a third party class, is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Comment: Somebody has any idea what could be happening

Comment: What are you setting the `message.From` property to?

Comment: I was using the wrong smtp server , it was smtp.live.com , thank you all