# C# Send email using Office 365 SMTP doesn't change given email display name

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, sendmail, mailaddress

I am using C# MailMessage for sending Email through office 365, and I want to change the display name of the sender in the email.

I have tried using mailMessage MailAddress Constructor like this

```
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email","display name");
```

but it doesn't solve the problem

But when I tried to use Gmail instead, the display name is changed.

Comment: Can you please try with this code inside btnSend_Click() method https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/sending-a-simple-email-using-smtpclient-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: I already used that way but the problem occurs only with Office 365 smtp, when I use Gmai it works fine.

Comment: Ok. What about this example, note the fully qualified email used.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35767267/10634638

Answer (score 0):

This is our generic SMTP email function.  It includes the sender's email address and name.

```
 public static bool EmailReport(
               String Subject,
               String Body,
               String FromAddress,
               String FromName
               String[] To,
               String[] CC,
               out String sError)
        {
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("<insert your email server name here i.e.: mail.Mycompany.com>");
            smtp.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            m.Subject = Subject;
            m.Body = Body;
            m.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress, FromName);
            foreach (String sTo in To)
            {
                m.To.Add(sTo);
            }
            if (CC != null)
            {
                foreach (String sCC in CC)
                {
                    m.CC.Add(sCC);
                }
            }
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(m);
                sError = "";
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sError = ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ahmad Jammal  = We're on O365 and it's been working since the first day we deployed it.  Check how your credentials are being passed into the function.