# vb,net - sending mail using net.mail and office 365

Tags: .net, email, office365, visual-studio-2019, smtpclient

I have a sendmail function i've used plenty of times before, only I've come to use it today using an office 365 account and its not working.

Code is as follows...

```
Public Function Sendmail(ByVal mailrecipient As String, ByVal mailsubject As String, ByVal mailbody As String)
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(mail_server_username, mail_server_password)
        SmtpServer.Port = internal_mail_server_port
        SmtpServer.Host = internal_mail_server
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress(mail_sender, "My Name")
        mail.To.Add(mailrecipient)
        mail.Subject = mailsubject
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        mail.Body = mailbody
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        Return "Success"

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Fail"
    End Try
End Function
```

The exception that is encountered is

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM .....

I know there is a bug with usedefaultcredentials whereby if you state this after providing your creds it resets your creds, so I've made sure I do that pretty much first.

I'm using the same address for mail_server_username and for mail_sender, so its not a sendas permission error.

I've had a look around and I found a post or two that suggests this method of sending mail is no longer valid with 365, but that didn't elaborate on why nor offer an alternative.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMTP 5.7.57 error when trying to send email via Office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751844/smtp-5-7-57-error-when-trying-to-send-email-via-office-365)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572583/c-sharp-send-email-with-office365-smtp