# Unable to send emails using C# code from GoDaddy configured Office 365 account

Tags: c#, email, office365, smtpclient

I have purchased "Office 365 Email Essentials" plan from GoDaddy for sending the emails. I am able to send and receive these emails in my outlook mailbox, but not programatically via C# code.
I keep receiving the error "

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
> authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not
> authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
> [BMXPR01CA0092.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx"));
        msg.From = new MailAddress("xxx@mydomain.com", "Admin");
        msg.Subject = "This is a Test Mail";
        msg.Body = "This is a test message using Exchange OnLine";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@mydomain.com", "mypassword","mydomain.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        //Send the msg
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

And here is the mailsettings entry in the config file -

```
<mailSettings>
<smtp from="xxx@mydomain.com">
  <network host="smtp.office365.com" port="587" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

The settings I see in the Outlook are -

Server name: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: STARTTLS

Alternatively, I also tried using the userid in place of actual email address in the network credentials,but that did not work either.

I also tried to use the MX Txt record in GoDaddy i.e. server "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" and port #25 ,but no luck.

I also changed the settings in "Mailbox delegation" as per the link http://edudotnet.blogspot.com/2014/02/smtp-microsoft-office-365-net-smtp.html , but that did not help either.

Please help me what am I missing in these steps.

Comment: I also tried disablng the firewall, adding inbound rules to allow TCP port 587, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMTP 5.7.57 error when trying to send email via Office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751844/smtp-5-7-57-error-when-trying-to-send-email-via-office-365)

Comment: Did yo usolve your problem ? I am currently experiencing the same and would appreciate if you post your solution here

Answer (score 7):

After spending hours on this, I have found that the smtp host for the godaddy configured office 365 mail id is "**smtpout.secureserver.net**".

Also program the client as closed connection like below:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient {

   Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net",

   Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME@DOMAIN.COM", "YOURPWD"),

   Port = 587,

   EnableSsl = true,

   Timeout = 10000

};
```

after these updates, it will work!!! Enjoy!

Example Console application code!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                string userId = "username@domainname.com";
                string _pwd = "mypassword";
                var toAddress = "touseremailaddress";
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net",
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userId, _pwd),
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true
                };
               
                var Msg = new MailMessage();
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(userId);
                Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress.ToString()));
                Msg.Subject = "TEST EMAIL";
                Msg.Body = "Hello world";

                Console.WriteLine("start to send email over SSL...");
                client.Send(Msg);
                Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  You definitely saved me a lot of troubleshooting, you rock!  A combination of this and enabling SMTP on the account did it for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try to change the SMTP server name to outlook.office365.com instead of smtp.office365.com

Comment: I tried but its giving me an error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [BMXPR01CA0002.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"