# Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server, connect error 10060"

Tags: .net, powershell, office365, mailmessage, asp.net-mail

I have the following code to connect to ExchangeOnline  >> generate csv file >> send the file by email using Office 365 smtp:-

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$SiteIDs = '64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e','20e6140c-0441-4988-b36c-c61cf3400847'
$Operations = @('FileAccessed','FileDownloaded','FileDeleted')
$OutputFile = ".\UnifiedAuditLog_FULL.csv"
$Today = Get-Date -Date (Get-Date -Format “yyyy-MM-dd”)
$intDays = 14
For ($i=0; $i -le $intDays; $i++){
  For ($j=23; $j -ge 0; $j--){
    $StartDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j)
    $EndDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j + 1)
    $Audit = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -ResultSize 5000 -SiteIds $SiteIDs -RecordType SharePointFileOperation -Operations $Operations 
    $ConvertAudit = $Audit | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
    $OutputFile0 = ".\UnifiedAuditLog_FULL"+$i+$j+"ALL0.csv"
    $ConvertAudit | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent | Export-Csv $OutputFile0 -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
    Write-Host $StartDate `t $Audit.Count
    # File to be attached in email
$attachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment("D:\"+$OutputFile0)

# Configure SMTP server
$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$mailMessage = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtpObj = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

# Set email parameters
$mailMessage.From = "***"
$mailMessage.ReplyTo = "****"
$mailMessage.To.Add("****")
$mailMessage.subject = "[MAIL SUBJECT]"
$mailMessage.body = "[MAIL BODY]"
$mailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

# Send email
$smtpObj.Send($mailMessage)
$attachment.Dispose()
  
  
  
  
  
  }
}
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

But i will get this exception:-

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server
response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 40.101.76.178 (40.101.76.178:25), connect error 10060"
At line:28 char:1
+ $smtpObj.Send($mailMessage)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

Any advice?

[image]

Update-1

Now when i define the port number as follow:-

```
$smtpObj = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer,587)
```

I will get this error instead:-

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is
required to send mail [VI1P194CA0025.EURP194.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"
At line:28 char:1
+ $smtpObj.Send($mailMessage)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

**Edit** I also tried this:-

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your tenant password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "O365.key"

Connect-ExchangeOnline
$SiteIDs = '64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e','20e6140c-0441-4988-b36c-c61cf3400847'
$Operations = @('FileAccessed','FileDownloaded','FileDeleted')
$OutputFile = ".\UnifiedAuditLog_FULL.csv"
$Today = Get-Date -Date (Get-Date -Format “yyyy-MM-dd”)
$intDays = 2
$TenantPass = cat "O365.key" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("test.user@***.com", $TenantPass)
For ($i=0; $i -le $intDays; $i++){
  For ($j=23; $j -ge 0; $j--){
    $StartDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j)
    $EndDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j + 1)
    $Audit = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -ResultSize 5000 -SiteIds $SiteIDs -RecordType SharePointFileOperation -Operations $Operations 
    $ConvertAudit = $Audit | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
    $OutputFile0 = ".\UnifiedAuditLog_FULL"+$i+$j+"ALL0.csv"
    $ConvertAudit | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent | Export-Csv $OutputFile0 -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
    Write-Host $StartDate `t $Audit.Count
    
    # File to be attached in email
$attachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment("D:\"+$OutputFile0)

# Configure SMTP server
$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$mailMessage = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtpObj = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer,587)
$smtpObj.EnableSSl = $true
$smtpObj.Credentials = $emailCredential
# Set email parameters
$mailMessage.From = "test.user@***.com"
$mailMessage.To.add("test.user@***.com")
$mailMessage.subject = "[MAIL SUBJECT]"
#$mailMessage.body = "[MAIL BODY]"
#$mailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

# Send email
$smtpObj.Send($mailMessage)
$attachment.Dispose()
  
  
  
  
  
  }
}
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

but i got this error:-

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139
Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your
administrator. [VI1P191CA0005.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"
At line:26 char:1
+ $smtpObj.Send($mailMessage)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

Although the user i am using has `SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled` = False, as follow

```
PS D:\> Get-CASMailbox -Identity test.user@***.com
Name          ActiveSyncEnabled OWAEnabled PopEnabled ImapEnabled MapiEnabled SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled
----          ----------------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------
test.user@***.com True              True       True       True        True        False
```

Comment: Try commenting out the body and the attachment and see if it works. Also add default credentials as shown in following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766928/how-to-set-username-and-password-for-smtpclient-object-in-net?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng i tried commenting out the body and the attachment >> and i define the credental as mentioned on the link you provided, but i got this error `Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139

Comment: ... Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [VI1PR0802CA0031.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com]" At line:28 char:1+ smtpObj.Send($mailMessage)+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException`

Comment: @johnGu Follow the instructions under where it says ["Enable SMTP AUTH for specific mailboxes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission#enable-smtp-auth-for-specific-mailboxes)

Comment: The FROM address and the credentials have to be from same account

Comment: @jdweng they are already .. but things are not working

Comment: The fixes now are allowing connection to complete, but you are failing when sending the email.  Are you failing first time through loops or after more than one email gets sent?

Comment: @jdweng fail on the first attempt

Comment: @jdweng can you check my edit please?

Comment: Are you inside a corporate network?  Is server a company server or you own account?  If you are inside a company firewall all smtp ports are forwarded to the company email proxy server where credentials are checked.  So you cannot get to an outside email server.  The error you are getting could be the Forwarding is sending the email to different server.

Comment: @jdweng i am in my home >> and i am trying to connect to Office 365 SMTP

Comment: Are you connecting to your personal account or into your company account?  You may be having issues getting into your company account.  Your personnel credentials may be used instead of the company credentials.  Try for credentials : smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648391/exception-using-default-smtp-credentials-on-office365-client-was-not-authentic?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng using  my compay account of course

Comment: You need to be inside the firewall.  if inside firewall you may be able to use port 25 instead of 587. It all depends on how your company has setup the smtp.  If company is using a relay you may not even need credentials.  Relay is used for devices like printers.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng i do not have any firewall.. i am connected from home

Comment: The firewall is at the company.  You are at home but the email server is inside a firewall at company.

Comment: @jdweng i am connected to the Office 365 smtp not to our company smtp